# Replace lua function call with 2 parameters across all files using shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I use Corona SDK, and they have made a change to their graphics library which means that all instances of the function setReferencePoint() have to be replaced with 2 properties "anchor.x" and "anchor.y". 
E.g

```
thePlayer:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)
```

becomes

```
thePlayer.anchorX, thePlayer.anchorY = 0, 0
```

Some of my projects have hundreds of instances of setReferencePoint(), so I tried to make a script which would automatically replace all instances for me. However I don't have much experience with shell scripts, so I haven't had much luck yet. This is my current script:

```
#!/bin/bash
OLD=":setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)"
NEW=".anchorX, .anchorY = 0, 0"
DPATH="/Users/me/Desktop/game/*.lua"
BPATH="/Users/me/Desktop/game/new"
[ ! -d $BPATH ] && mkdir -p $BPATH || :
for f in $DPATH
do
  if [ -f $f -a -r $f ]; then
    /bin/cp -f $f $BPATH
    sed -i "s/$OLD/$NEW/g" "/Users/me/Desktop/game/new/$f.lua"
   else
    echo "Error: Cannot read $f"
  fi
done
```

I'm getting an error which says "command a expects \ followed by text", but even if I get past that I have another issue. I would need to retrieve the variable name before the ":setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)" in my code, so that I could insert it before the ".anchorY" part of the NEW string.

Is that even possible in a script like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OLD="\(\w*\):setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)"
NEW="\1.anchorX, \1.anchorY = 0, 0"
```

The `\(` `\)` denote a subexpression; `\1` is replaced by the value of the first (and in this example only) subexpression.